# The newly created GCP load balancer cannot be used

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

We found that the newly created TCP load balancer cannot be used
Try creating it in your own project

The front-end 34.111.65.103:1883
The front-end 35.207.130.7:9300
The back-end 34.159.84.202:22
[image]

I found that when THE IP is Standard, the port can pass.
I found that when IP is Premium, the port cannot pass.

You can test it. If the problem is the same as mine, please use GCP to feedback this case.
Expect GCP to be fixed soon.

[image]

Comment: 34.111.0.0/17 bug

Comment: Network load balancers is a pass-through load balancer and doesn't proxy connections to your backend instances.It forwards all incoming connections to your backend services if the port matches without modifying the source IP address of the client as long as your backends are passing the health-checks. The load balancer shouldn't be able to actively "refused" connections.Make sure that you have proper firewalls & health checks as per the given Documentation [Check](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#fw-netlb)

Comment: Also Refer to [Healthcheck](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/#about-nlb)